# Gateway NV59C (Windows 7) Connecting to a tv via HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, tv, gateway

I have connected my laptop to my tv via HDMI cable, and I get a picture on my tv, however, my tv does not put audio out; instead the laptop plays the audio. How do I switch it, so my tv plays the audio and not my laptop?

When I bring up the Playback Devices, the list does not show anything corresponding to the HDMI port; all it shows is Speakers-Realtek High Definition Audio-Default Device

Comment: When I bring up the Playback Devices, the list does not show anything corresponding to the HDMI port; all it shows is Speakers-Realtek High Definition Audio-Default Device

Comment: Ypur added info is better added as part of your question.  I have updated your original post

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your default audio output device to the HDMI port. Right-click on your volume icon in your taskbar and choose *Playback devices*. In the list, you should see one corresponding to the HDMI port. Select it and then click the *Set Default* button, and then click OK. Sound should be coming from the TV, now.

Comment: When I bring up the Playback Devices, the list does not show anything corresponding to the HDMI port; all it shows is Speakers-Realtek High Definition Audio-Default Device.

Comment: @AubreyPerkins Is this when the TV is hooked up to the HDMI port and displaying a picture? On my laptop, an entry won't appear until I connect an external display to the HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

Not all HDMI ports support audio.  I do not think your video card (HDMI port) supports audio.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this, or am I SOL?

Comment: Not if the video card does not support it. You can plug some portable speakers into the headphone jack for sound.